# ffmpeg Command Fails in C

Tags: c, bash, ffmpeg, command

I have a program that stitches together files in ffmpeg using the system() function.  It works when I run the command normally, but fails when I run it through the C program (it gets like 80% of the way through then fails saying

```
[concat @ 0x7fe299801000] Impossible to open '/Us' parts.txt: No such file or directory
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
```

But that only happens in the C program.  Not when I run the exact same command manually.

The command it's running is

```
char command[1024];
sprintf(command, "ffmpeg -f concat -i parts.txt -c copy s%de%02d.ts", season, episode);
system(command);
```

And the parts.txt file is as follows: http://pastebin.com/pUAu9mbt

(Before you ask, yes those are absolute pathnames, not relative)

Comment: Here's an idea. Try doing just the first half of the files and if that works try doing just the second half - then you'll see if the problem lies in the sheer overall volume (probably a memory issue) or in the second half of the files (probably a coding issue).

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you don't need ffmpeg to concat transport streams. Just append each file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell it's definitely not a memory issue as I have plenty to spare and am allocating plenty.  Plus some batches are failing at their 80% which is more than the complete set of another episode (just because it has more parts than the other).

@szatmary I originally tried that actually using the `cat` command.  The filesize was correct but when I tried playing it it only contained the video/audio for the first file for some reason.